# Raise exception for Java.Lang.Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

`Java.Lang.Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` catches only exceptions by the Android runtime. I tried to throw a native exception with

```
Java.Lang.Integer.ParseInt("xxx");
```

but the exception is not catched by the `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`. This is my implementation:

*Application subclass*:

```
// OnCreate
UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler();
uncaughtHandler.UncaughtExceptionHandled += OnUncaughtExceptionHandled;
Java.Lang.Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = uncaughtHandler;

private void OnUncaughtExceptionHandled(object sender, Throwable ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler");
}
```

*Additional class:*

```
private class UncaughtExceptionHandler : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<Throwable> UncaughtExceptionHandled;

    public void UncaughtException(Java.Lang.Thread thread, Throwable ex)
    {
        if (UncaughtExceptionHandled != null)
        {
            UncaughtExceptionHandled(null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I throw an exception that is catched by the `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`? Is it a good idea to catch unmanaged exceptions in managed code?

Answer (score 0):

You need just a throw new Exception after UncaughtExceptionHandler was initialized

```
throw new DivideByZeroException();
```

> Is it a good idea to catch unmanaged exceptions in managed code?

Yeap. Crashlytics(Crash Report Library) - works in the same way.

Comment: I already tried that, but the exception is not catched by `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`. If I use `AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser` then the exception is catched only on the device.

Comment: Isn't `DivideByZeroException` a managed exception? Because `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` seems to only catch unmanaged exceptions. Does it matter where `DivideByZeroException` is thrown (*MainActivity*, ...)?